# How configure Authentification OWIN with asp.net MVC + Postgresql?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, authentication, owin, identity

I'm migrating an application into another language and have already extensive data base with users.
but I wanted to work with the identity Owin, but still do not quite understand.
when i

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
    if (user != null)
    {
      await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
      return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
    }
  }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Where do the comparison?
How does he know which table and fields of Postgres database table?

in file startup:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account. 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });           
    }
}
```